# Why can rails not provide has_and_belongs_to_many polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

Rails allows for polymorphic associations and has_and_belongs_to_many / has_many :through associations; but seemingly not together - or at least well.

**Example set-up:**

```
Competition
  has_many :contestants, through: :competition_competitors

CompetitionContestant
  belong_to :competition
  belongs_to :contestant, :polymorphic: true

FootballTeam
  has_many :competitions, as: :contestant, through: :competition_contestants
RugbyTeam
  has_many :competitions, as: :contestant, through: :competition_contestants
Singer
  has_many :competitions, as: :contestant, through: :competition_contestants
```

**Solution**:

You specify the source_type but then you must maintain a list of the relevant polymorphic classes which doesn't feel RAILSy.

```
  has_many :football_teams through: :competition_contestants, source_type: :contestant, source_class: "FootballTeam"
  has_many :rugby_players through: :competition_contestants, source_type: :contestant, source_class: "RugbyTeam"
  has_many :singers through: :competition_contestants, source_type: :contestant, source_class: "Singer"
```

**Or**

You can make an association to the intermediary and create your own functions. But then you don't get all the collection methods/operators has_many :through provides.
e.g.

```
Competition
  def contestants
    competition_contestants.map(&:contestants)
```

Is there a good reason why rails doesn't allow has_many :through associations to polymorphic classes? If the type and id are stored in the intermediary, why can it not be inferred which classes associated in the has_many :through declaration?

Comment: `has_and_belongs_to_many` is really just a simple headless association without a join model - with no join model you can't have a polymorphic association. Its really only useful in the simplest of scenarios (read almost never).

Comment: As for indirect polymorphic associations - yes they are possible. But they are a really leaky abstraction as its not really homogeneous collection. Consider for example what happens with ordering when your are pulling records from x different tables. They are a potential performance nightmare due to the lack of eager loading and a maintenance nightmare due to the lack of referential integrity.